# Time and Date Edit by GMT Zone

Tags: google-sheets

I need to edit the date and time format in a Google spreadsheet. 
The spreadsheet has 300 rows with the following format in text 2016-04-21 21:28:00 +0000.
Using the find and replace feature I would like to change the +0000 to -7000 which in turn will decrease the time by 7 hrs.

This 2016-04-21 21:28:00 +0000 turn to this 2016-04-14 21:28:00 -7000.

How can I achieve this change?

Comment: Are these dates entered as text, or as `Dates`? Could you share a (read-only) link to your spreadsheet, or another spreadsheet demonstrating the problem? It would make it much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

If these dates are entered in your spreadsheet *as text*, you will need to use text replacement functions. Luckily, Google Spreadsheets supports find & replace with [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). So:

1. Click *Edit → Find and replace*.
2. Check the *Search using regular expressions* checkbox
3. In the *Find* field, enter `(\d+-\d+-\d+\s\d+\:\d+\:\d+)\s(\+0000)`
4. In the *Replace with* field, enter `$1 +0700`

Click *Replace* (or *Replace all*, if you're feeling lucky).

Explained:
The expression entered into the *Find* field is a regular expression, which matches 1) a number: `\d+`, 2) a dash `-`, 3) another number `\d+`, and so on. It is a pattern for a datetime in your format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS +ZZZZ`. Note that the regular expression has parenthesizes around the date/time part, but not around the timezone part.

The expression in the *Replace with* field says "take the first group (enclosed in parenthesizes), `$1`, and append `-0700` to it".

If you want to learn more about using regular expressions (which can be useful in many situations), there are many good resources on line. These are some good ones:

- http://regexone.com/
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/